# what kind of html element is used for users to input an order?

Tags: html

basically I have some SQL and I want the user to be able to select the ordering in the "order by" section with an HTML element. Are there any out-of-the-box solutions?

edit: it's more like `order by country,status,...` or `order by status,country,...`

Comment: wow, your edit changed the question entirely! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if u display your sql results in a list view u can change display order by clicking on the header of your displayed fields.

EDIT: have a look at [this](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-option-sort-key.html). (hold down shift key and click on headers)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `select` to choose which category to search through, and then a radio button to choose ascending or descending order.

### Dropdown

```
<select name='search'>
    <option>Name</option>
    <option>Telephone</option>
    <option>Address</option>
</select>
```

### Radio Buttons

```
<input type='radio' name='order' value='asc' /> Ascending
<input type='radio' name='order' value='desc' /> Descending​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Not knowing what server-side technology you're using somewhat limits the question, but basically get the value from the `select`, and then order depending on the radio button.